# Vue Cli error when using npm "npm install -g @vue/cli"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I'm using:

- windows 10
- node.js 12
- npm 6

In cmd when I run the following command to install Vue Cli:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I get the this problem:

> ```
> C:\Windows\System32>vue --version
> 'vue' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
> ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
>
> C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g @vue/cli
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."^3.12.1","istanbul":'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\KHALED\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-11T13_22_34_143Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`? It looks like your package.json is not a valid json.

Comment: Try steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60617312/3226121)

Answer (score 0):

Try using these commands in the same order-

```
      npm install vue
      npm cache clean --force
      npm install -g @vue/cli
```

If this doesn't work try using VPN and reinstalling Node