# create-react-app: invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/loose-envify

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I've been trying to run create react app using npx for over 2 days switching to different Wifis + Ethernet but I get `Invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/loose-envify` all the time.

I thought it was an internet speed connection problem but it wasn't

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/loose-envify reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/deestarks/.npm/_logs/2021-04-12T18_55_27_266Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file? Or is that the issue, it has an error and then gets deleted? What command are you running to create this new React project?

Comment: @DrewReese I don't have a `package.json`. It gets deleted when the error occurs. And I issue the command with `npx create-react-app appname`

Comment: And any extra details in the generated log: `/home/deestarks/.npm/_logs/2021-04-12T18_55_27_266Z-debug.log`? Do you have the required versions of Node/npm installed: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#creating-an-app.

Comment: No extra details

Answer (score 1):

I had and resolved similar issue here: [npm install failed, npm ERR! invalid json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382322/npm-install-failed-npm-err-invalid-json-response)

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and

```
npm cache verify
```

then

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

and finally, I was able to run

```
npm i
```

The similar question was there: [npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...registry.npmjs.org/@i'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387743/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-registry-npmjs-org)

Answer (score 0):

run this command and it will solve your issue

```sh
sudo npm cache clean --force
```