# npm install failed, npm ERR! invalid json response

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
> npm WARN Found: bootstrap@3.4.1
> npm WARN node_modules/@ivan/data-insights/node_modules/bootstrap
> npm WARN   bootstrap@"^3.3.7" from @ivan/data-insights@1.7.26
> npm WARN   node_modules/@ivan/data-insights
> npm WARN     @ivan/data-insights@"1.7.26" from the root project
> npm WARN
> npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peer bootstrap@"^4.3.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.4.0
> npm WARN node_modules/@ivan/data-insights/node_modules/bootstrap-switch
> npm WARN   bootstrap-switch@"^3.4.0" from @ivan/data-insights@1.7.26
> npm WARN   node_modules/@ivan/data-insights
> npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
> npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
> npm ERR! invalid json response body at http://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fparser reason: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 103148

Comment: I resolved this one: `npm cache clean --force` and `npm cache verify` then `npm i npm@latest -g` and finally, I successfully ran `npm i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error's saying there exists already a version of bootstrap in your project. Try to remove bootstrap and install again. OR Remove the node_modules and run `npm install` again to install your packages.

Comment: nothing to remove, no any node modules yet

Answer (score 1):

I have already resolved this issue in the following way:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and

```
npm cache verify
```

then

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

and finally, I was able to run

```
npm i
```

The similar question was there: [npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...registry.npmjs.org/@i'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387743/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-registry-npmjs-org)